# How to set TimePickerDialog from 9AM to 4PM

Tags: android, android-timepicker, timepickerdialog

I have a school based android application and it has using TimePickerDialog.  In DatePickerDialog there have an option for setMinDate and setMaxDate.
`datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);              datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`

Like that I need to set minimum and maximum time. Means user can click time from 9.00 am to 4.00 pm. Is it possible with TimePickerDialog?

```
CustomEditTextNormal input_time = (CustomEditTextNormal)sheetView.findViewById(R.id.input_time);
            input_time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                    mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                            input_time.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                        }
                    }, hour, minute, false);
                    mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                    mTimePicker.show();
                }
            });
```